# Can't get audio to play with video player in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It seems like there are a million posts about this topic, but I have tried every solution I can find in every thread I read, and it still is not working for me. Basically, I have a script that adds a video player component to a gameobject and sets all necessary values, then plays it.

Most of what I have read online tells me that I should add this code to make audio work:

```
videoPlayer.controlledAudioTrackCount = 1;
videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);
```

And that I should add aforementioned block of code before videoPlayer.Prepare(). Unfortunately, it is still not working. So I am providing my script in case somebody can find my error and help me.

Here it is. This is the whole thing. Sorry if it is long, but I'm not sure what the issue is, so I figure I should provide more info in case it is something I wouldn't have expected. There are a few calls to other scripts, but they are minor and shouldn't impact your ability to understand the nature of the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using Ibuprogames.CameraTransitionsAsset;

public class PlayVideoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CrossFade crossFade;
    private GameManagerScript gameManager;
    private CameraTransition cameraTransition;
    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    private SpriteRenderer bgdSR;
    public VideoClip videoClip;
    public enum TargetAudioSource { SFX, Music, Master }
    public TargetAudioSource targetAudioSource;
    public bool interruptMusic = false; //Only applicable if Music Audio Source is selected
    private Camera thisCamera;
    public Camera destinationCamera;
    public enum TransitionToNewCamera { Cut, Crossfade, PanLeft, PanRight, PanUp, PanDown, CrossZoom }
    public TransitionToNewCamera transition;
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private bool videoDone;
    private Camera[] allCams;
    private bool videoPrepared;
    AudioSource master1;
    AudioSource m1;
    AudioSource m2;
    AudioSource sfx1;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SetCamera();
        if (thisCamera == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("thisCamera is null in PlayVideoScript");
        }

        master1 = GameObject.Find("Master Audio Source").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        m1 = GameObject.Find("Music Audio Source 1").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        m2 = GameObject.Find("Music Audio Source 2").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        sfx1 = GameObject.Find("SFX Audio Source 1").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        bgdSR = gameObject.transform.parent.transform.parent.Find("Background").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManagerScript>();
        crossFade = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<CrossFade>();
        if (cameraTransition == null)
        {
            cameraTransition = FindObjectOfType<CameraTransition>();
        }
        CreateVideoPlayer();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;
        videoPlayer.prepareCompleted += PlayVideo;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (videoDone)
        {
            GameManagerScript.originalCamera = thisCamera;
            GameManagerScript.destinationCamera = destinationCamera;
            switch (transition)
            {
                case TransitionToNewCamera.Cut:
                    thisCamera.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    destinationCamera.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    break;

                case TransitionToNewCamera.Crossfade:
                    crossFade.CrossFadeTransition(thisCamera, destinationCamera, 1);
                    break;

                case TransitionToNewCamera.PanLeft:
                    crossFade.PanTransitionHorizontal(thisCamera, destinationCamera, false, gameManager.transSpeedSlider.value);
                    break;

                case TransitionToNewCamera.PanRight:
                    crossFade.PanTransitionHorizontal(thisCamera, destinationCamera, true, gameManager.transSpeedSlider.value);
                    break;

                case TransitionToNewCamera.PanUp:
                    crossFade.PanTransitionVertical(thisCamera, destinationCamera, true, gameManager.transSpeedSlider.value);
                    break;

                case TransitionToNewCamera.PanDown:
                    crossFade.PanTransitionVertical(thisCamera, destinationCamera, false, gameManager.transSpeedSlider.value);
                    break;

                case TransitionToNewCamera.CrossZoom:
                    cameraTransition.DoTransition(CameraTransitionEffects.CrossZoom, thisCamera, destinationCamera, 1.0f, false);
                    break;
            }
            videoDone = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUpAsButton()
    {
        if (videoPlayer == null)
        {
            CreateVideoPlayer();
        }
        if (thisCamera == null)
        {
            SetCamera();
        }

        switch (targetAudioSource)
        {
            case TargetAudioSource.Master:
                audioSource = master1;
                audioSource.volume = Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.InverseLerp(gameManager.masterVolumeSlider.minValue, gameManager.masterVolumeSlider.maxValue, gameManager.masterVolumeSlider.value));
                break;

            case TargetAudioSource.Music:
                audioSource.volume = Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.InverseLerp(gameManager.musicVolumeSlider.minValue, gameManager.musicVolumeSlider.maxValue, gameManager.musicVolumeSlider.value));
                if (interruptMusic)
                {
                    if (m1.isPlaying)
                    {
                        audioSource = m1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        audioSource = m2;
                    }
                }
                else if (!interruptMusic)
                {
                    if (m2.isPlaying)
                    {
                        audioSource = m1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        audioSource = m2;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case TargetAudioSource.SFX:
                audioSource = sfx1;
                audioSource.volume = GameManagerScript.sfxVolume;
                break;
        }

        videoPlayer.controlledAudioTrackCount = 1;
        videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
        videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);
        audioSource.clip = null;
        videoPlayer.frame = 0;
        videoPlayer.Prepare();

    }

    void PlayVideo(VideoPlayer player)
    {
        videoPlayer.Play();
        audioSource.Play();
        StartCoroutine(DelayVideo());
    }

    IEnumerator DelayVideo()
    {
        const int numFramesDelay = 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < numFramesDelay; i++)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        bgdSR.enabled = false;
    }

    void CreateVideoPlayer()
    {
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>() != null)
        {
            videoPlayer = bgdSR.gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        }
        else
        {
            videoPlayer = bgdSR.gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>() as VideoPlayer;
        }
        videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
        videoPlayer.clip = videoClip;
        videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
        videoPlayer.isLooping = false;
        videoPlayer.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.CameraFarPlane;
        videoPlayer.targetCamera = thisCamera;
        videoPlayer.enabled = true;

    } //--End CreateVideoPlayer()

    void SetCamera()
    {
        allCams = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Camera>();
        foreach (Camera c in allCams)
        {
            if (c.transform.parent == transform.parent.transform.parent)
            {
                thisCamera = c;
            }
        }
    }

    void EndReached(VideoPlayer player)
    {
        audioSource.Stop();
        videoPlayer.Pause();
        audioSource.volume = 0;
        videoDone = true;
    }
}
```

There is one thing that I suspect might have something to do with it, which is that I have to set the audio clip to null since I use the same AudioSource to play other things in the scene. If I don't clear it, it just plays whatever was played last.

How am I supposed to set the clip when using it for a Video Player?

Answer (score 0):

In your OnMouseUpAsButton(), you are spawning the Videoplayer using CreateVideoplayer function that sets videoclip.clip. On the same method[OnMouseUpAsButton], you are setting the clip to null and frame to 0. Its like when the videoplayer gets spawned, it will set the clip inside CreateVideoplayer function and then set its clip to null from OnMouseUpAsButton function.
You may need to remove Those 2 lines and your code will work fine.

here is the code that I use to stream video. Create a class "[YourClass.cs]" and paste the code.

```
public RawImage image;

public VideoClip videoToPlay;

private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
private VideoSource videoSource;

private AudioSource audioSource;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;
}

IEnumerator playVideo()
{

    //Add VideoPlayer to the GameObject
    videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();

    //Add AudioSource
    audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

    //Disable Play on Awake for both Video and Audio
    videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
    audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
    audioSource.Pause();

    //We want to play from video clip not from url

    videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;

    // Vide clip from Url
    //videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
    //videoPlayer.url = "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4";


    //Set Audio Output to AudioSource
    videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;

    //Assign the Audio from Video to AudioSource to be played
    videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
    videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);

    //Set video To Play then prepare Audio to prevent Buffering
    videoPlayer.clip = videoToPlay;
    videoPlayer.Prepare();

    //Wait until video is prepared
    while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("Done Preparing Video");

    //Assign the Texture from Video to RawImage to be displayed
    image.texture = videoPlayer.texture;

    //Play Video
    videoPlayer.Play();

    //Play Sound
    audioSource.Play();

    Debug.Log("Playing Video");
    while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Video Time: " + Mathf.FloorToInt((float)videoPlayer.time));
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("Done Playing Video");
    UIManager.Instance.OnSkipVideo();
}


public void PlayVideo() {
    StartCoroutine(playVideo());

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it didn't work. You mentioned that I am setting the clip, and then setting it to null, but when I set the clip in videoPlayer, I am setting the VIDEO clip, but when I am setting the clip to null, I am setting the AUDIO clip (caps for emphasis, not shouting). Like I said before, if I don't clear audio clip from the audio source, it will just play whatever had been played last, not the audio from the video.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did an oopsie (pewdiepie level lol). I am working with a team and I was unaware that my team member responsible for the videos had yet to encode the audio track. So...

The script actually works. If anybody is looking for a script that will add a video component and play a video OnMouseUp (over a collider), then this might save you some time. Note: You won't be able to copy and paste the whole thing because I am using Unity assets or custom scripts, but you should be able to get close.